# SQL - Remove everything between [ and ]

Tags: sql, t-sql, substring

I am trying to find a solution for this specification, I have a list of data, stored on a table, we have 2 views for the same column, basically we have one that is visible only to clerks, in a specific page, the other is for end-users, website users, etc.

The fields can contain any form of text, however, when a clerk inputs "foo [bar]",

I am showing "foo [bar]" to clerks, but I need to keep just "foo" for the end-user.

The other interesting requirement is that for long texts the clerks may sometimes just open square bracket and not close, in this scenario it must run till the end of the string.

What I have tried and been going around on is the following:

```
SELECT 
    [Name] = 
        CASE
        WHEN [value] LIKE '%\[%' ESCAPE '\'
            THEN SUBSTRING( [value], PATINDEX( '%[%', [value] ), LEN( [value] ) )
            ELSE [value]
        END
FROM #MyTable
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like something for your application layer, which hopefully supports Regex, not the SQL Server back end, which does *not* support Regex and does not excel at string manipulation.

Comment: My above holds even more true if you have values like `'foo [bar] yes [no]'`, and need `'foo yes` as the result.

Comment: that is not in the specs, but I will not exclude, however, I was hoping for a SQL solution for the simple fact that, it's in a stored procedure, guess in that case, I'll have to add a layer that captures the returned data and processes accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A late solution. Long as well. But it works for everything I throw at it...

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f7605cb2807d98430bd65ced57489da3) to see the solution in action.

**Sample data**

```
create table samples
(
  id int,
  input nvarchar(30)
);

insert into samples (id, input) values
(1, 'foo [bar]'),
(2, 'foo [bar abc'),
(3, 'foo [bar] more'),
(4, 'foo1 ! foo2 [bar] foo3'),
(5, 'foo1 foo2'),
(6, 'foo[bar]foo[bar]foo'),
(7, '[bar] foo');
```

**Solution**

Hooray for common table expressions. Each CTE has its purpose described in the comments.

```
-- split on '['
with cte1 as (
  select s.id, s.input, 1 as Starts, charindex('[', s.input) as Pos, 1 as CteId
  from samples s
    union all
  select cte1.id, cte1.input, cte1.Pos + 1, charindex('[', cte1.input, cte1.Pos + 1), 1
  from cte1
  where cte1.Pos > 0
),
-- split on ']'
cte2 as (
  select s.id, s.input, 1 as Starts, charindex(']', s.input) as Pos, 2 as CteId
  from samples s
    union all
  select cte2.id, cte2.input, cte2.Pos + 1, charindex(']', cte2.input, cte2.Pos + 1), 2
  from cte2
  where cte2.Pos > 0
),
-- combine both split result sets
cte as (
  select * from cte1
    union all
  select * from cte2
),
-- construct ranges by fetching end position of previous row
range as (
  select cte.id,
         cte.input,
         cte.Starts,
         lag(cte.Pos) over(partition by cte.Id order by cte.Starts, cte.CteId) as Ends,
         cte.CteId
  from cte
),
-- select substrings from Starts to just for Ends
subs as (
  select r.id,
         r.input,
         r.Starts,
         --r.Ends-1 as Ends,
         substring(r.input, r.Starts, case when r.Ends > 0 then r.Ends - r.Starts else len(r.input) end) as Sub
  from range r
  where r.CteId = 2
)
-- concatenate and remove duplicates
-- VERSION 1 (SQL Server 2017 and later)
select s.id, s.input, string_agg(s.Sub, '') within group(order by s.Starts) as Ret
from subs s
group by s.id, s.input
order by s.id;
/*
-- VERSION 2 (before SQL Server 2017)
select distinct s.id, s.input, x.Ret
from subs s
cross apply ( select s2.Sub + ''
              from subs s2
              where s2.id = s.id
              for xml path('') ) x(Ret)
order by s.id;
*/
```

**Result**

Contains some trailing/leading spaces that could be handled with `trim()` (like [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=797aeee39eb4acce83264f83d7a53577)).

```
id |input                 |Ret
---|----------------------|-----------------
1  |foo [bar]             |foo 
2  |foo [bar abc          |foo 
3  |foo [bar] more        |foo  more
4  |foo1 ! foo2 [bar] foo3|foo1 ! foo2  foo3
5  |foo1 foo2             |foo1 foo2
6  |foo[bar]foo[bar]foo   |foofoofoo
7  |[bar] foo             | foo
```

Comment: Copied everything into sql for testing, for some reason I am getting "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 61
Incorrect syntax near '('." for the following line: "select s.id, s.input, string_agg(s.Sub, '') within group(order by s.Starts) as Ret"

Comment: You did not specify your version of SQL Server. That is why I included 2 versions (second version is commented). The `string_agg()` function is only available starting from SQL Server 2017. [This fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=30e2a249b0786a28697f373e8cc4069b) is running on SQL Server 2016 with the second version uncommented and includes the space trimming.